# $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi x^2}\cdot e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx = e^{\pi\xi^2}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis

Prove that for all $\xi \in \mathbb{C}$,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi x^2}\cdot e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx = e^{\pi\xi^2}$$

I don't really know how to compute this integral. Can you please help me?

Comment: Hint: Complete the square in the exponent.

Comment: Hint: Think Fourier Transform

Comment: @VladimirLenin: I haven't study Fourier Transform yet, so I don't really know about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution avoiding the residu theorem or any change of variables over the complex plane.

Let $g(\xi)$ be the left hand side :$$g(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-\pi x^2}e^{-2i\pi x\xi}dx.$$
One can easily check that $f:\mathbb R\times \mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb C$ given by $f:(x,\xi)\mapsto e^{-\pi x^2}e^{-2i\pi x\xi}$ satisfies :

1. $f$ is measruable,
2. $\xi\mapsto f(x,\xi)$ is holomorphic for every $x\in \mathbb R$,
3. for any $R>0$, $$|f(x,z)|\leq e^{-\pi x^2}e^{2\pi x R}$$ where the right hand side belongs to $L^1(\mathbb R)$.

Hence, $g$ is a holomorphic function over $\mathbb C$ and one has $$ g'(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb R} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \xi}(x,\xi)dx.$$
However, using integration by parts, we get :
$$\begin{array}{rcl} g'(\xi) & = & \displaystyle \int_{\mathbb R} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \xi}(x,\xi)dx\\
& = & \displaystyle  i\int_{\mathbb R} -2x\pi e^{-\pi x^2}e^{-2i\pi x\xi}dx \\
& = & -2\pi \xi g(\xi).\end{array}$$

Since $g(0)=1$ (this is a Gaussian integral), $g$ satisfies $$\left\{\begin{array}{l} y'(\xi)=-2\pi y(\xi) \\ y(0)=1\end{array}\right.$$ and so does $\xi \mapsto \exp(-\pi \xi ^2)$.

Thus, $$g(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-\pi x^2}e^{-2i\pi x\xi}dx=\exp(\color{red}-\pi \xi ^2).$$

Answer (score 2):

By noticing that 
$$a x^{2} + b x = \left( \sqrt{a} x + \frac{b}{2 \sqrt{a}} \right)^{2} - \frac{b^{2}}{4 a}$$
then
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a x^{2} - b x} \, dx \\
&= e^{\frac{b^{2}}{4 a}} \, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{- \left( \sqrt{a} x + \frac{b}{2 \sqrt{a}} \right)^{2}} \, dx 
\end{align}
Making the change $t = \sqrt{a} x + \frac{b}{2 \sqrt{a}}$ leads to
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \, e^{\frac{b^{2}}{4 a}} \, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-t^{2}} \, dt \\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{a}} \, e^{\frac{b^{2}}{4 a}} \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t^{2}} \, dt \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \, e^{\frac{b^{2}}{4 a}} \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- u} \, u^{-1/2} \, du \hspace{5mm} \mbox{ where } t = \sqrt{u} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \, e^{\frac{b^{2}}{4 a}}.
\end{align}
Hence 
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a x^{2} - b x} \, dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \, e^{\frac{b^{2}}{4 a}}.
\end{align}

For the case $a = \pi$ and $b = 2 \pi i \, \eta$ the result becomes
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{- \pi x^{2} - 2 \pi i \eta x} \, dx =  e^{- \pi \eta^{2}}.
\end{align}

Comment: The final result is correct, but there are some important points that should be mentioned in the derivation. The integral is no longer over the real axis when performing the substitution so it's not a real integral anymore. To evaluate it properly one needs to find a suitable contour and then invoke the residue theorem (or similar).

Comment: Hey, my friend.  +1 Just one caution here is the the change of variable changes the limits to $-\infty-i\xi$ to $\infty-i\xi$.  Then, using the residue theorem, one can deform the contour to $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: @Dr.MV You and Winther have made valid statements. I saw the general form first then when reducing constants noticed the term $i$. It is true that it would deform the integral from the real line to the complex plane.

Comment: So why  does this work? I have never gotten an incorrect result by naively doing complex math in real integrals and then returning to real expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$-\pi x^2 - 2\pi i x \xi = -\pi(x^2+2ix\xi) = -\pi(x+i\xi)^2+(?)$$

Try to figure out what $(?)$ should be, and you should get something resembling a known integral. You might have to do some substitutions and/or contour deformations.